# Spacing between superposed divs, without affecting width

Tags: javascript, html, css, owl-carousel

I have been trying recently to make a slide of divs, using a script named Owl-Carousel, where divs are spaced by 10 px each so dragging looks nice.

I made the whole code for showing purpose:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLZmWd

I tried modifying the margins without success.

The CSS is as follow:

```
.generic { // header on top of slide, must have wrapper width
  background-color:red;
  height: 30px;
  text-align:center;
}

.item { // item (slide) inside the owl carousel, must have wrapper width
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #7FFFD4;
  //margin-right:10px; // gives the spacing between slides, but works so bad
}

#wrapper { // wraps carousel and elements with generic class
  margin:0px auto;
  width:720px;
  height: auto;
}
```

How can I space slides between each other by 10px while keeping red/green areas same width and .generic class untouched.

The reason I want the class ".generic" to be unchanged is mainly the way I've sat up my code, so that the CSS is easily modifiable for widths: I have a lot of different classes/elements which are supposed to take the wrapper width, I wish not to have to set width for each of them or set margins, for code manageability.

EDIT: To make it clear, when using mouse dragging on the carousel, my objective is to see 10px of white between each slide green slide (which isn't the case in the codepen) while keeping the green area width the same as the red area width.

Thanks

Comment: Am I missing something, or are they already the same width?

Comment: ''so that each green slide has spacing of 10px'' - actually, i don't understand this part, to be honest.

Comment: The slides are the same width, but they are not spaced by 10px, they're "fused" together if I could say!

Comment: @nevermind : when using mouse dragging from left to right for example, you'll see that each slide isn't spaced. what i want to to see "white" between two green slides, 10px of white to be precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... i think this is what you want:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbLdpv

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

      navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
      slideSpeed : 300,
      paginationSpeed : 400,
      singleItem:true,
    afterMove: function (elem) {

      var index = this.owl.currentItem;

     $('.owl-wrapper').css('margin-left',-10*(index)+'px')
    }

 });
});
```

To get desired behavior, you must move container (.owl-wrapper) - default position is always left:0, **but, since we want border** - we must move it accordingly. In CSS (if i remember well:)), i've just added:

```
.owl-item {
   border-right:10px solid white; 


}
```

EDIT2: margin-left, instead left, now should work in all (modern) browsers. :)

Comment: wow works well buddy, thanks! ended up using border transparency (10 px solid transparent) because I wanted it to match the background color, but it works flawless!! before i accept the answer, i wonder. do you think of a nice way to actually get rid of the hardcoded value "-10" inside the html, so that I'd only have to modify css fields in order to make it work? im a beginner in js, while i have a small idea of what i could do i thought maybe i could benefit from your knowledge yet again

Comment: Np, btw, not sure about hard coded value in html(?), because i added it to jquery part... you can modify that value, according to value set in css...;)

Comment: what i meant is that, instead of having at two places the value "10", just having it at one place, inside the CSS. reason is that I'm doing a css.php script that permits users to change some settings such as the border spacing, so it comes handy to only have one place to have "10". But it's not a big deal either, I was just curious.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a margin to your `meow`s and add a container around each of them, which makes them smaller than the total size of the container, adding margin. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOopOK

You can also use box-sizing to the same effect if you do not want to change the HTML. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbLdbG

However, I would recommend you develop this functionality yourself and don't use owl-carousel, especially if you are just learning JS. It isn't a particularly complex concept, though certainly outside the scope of a stackoverflow answer.

Comment: i indeed tried to set margin-right first hand, and it does work, but for this solution to be used, i must also set right margin of the red area (to keep both areas same width), which i prefer not doing, because i'll end up having to do it for a huge deal of classes in my real world application (it's possible, just doesnt ease maintainability). as for owl, im using it mainly because integrating it in AJAX context is easy and well done

Comment: @Yannick I don't believe you can do exactly what you want given your current constraints, however I've provided two alternatives in my updated answer.